# jQuery, условие Если все div имеют display none то

Tags: jquery

Скажите пожалуйста, как написать условие, если у всех div списка стоит display: none то что то сделать, а если не у всех, то ничего не делать. 
Сейчас имеем такой код:

```
<div class="line_table">
<div>

</div>

<div>

</div>

<div>

</div>

</div>
```

При нажатии на кнопку, там происходит поиск слов на совпадение, и к тем div, в которым не нашло совпадение по словам, присваивает style: diplay: none. Я написал вот такой скрипт:

```
    $(".bottom_line_table > div").each(function() {
    if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
       $('.not_found_table').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {

    }
});
```

Но он срабатывает всегда, даже если в списке есть div, с display: block.

Comment: потому что ты вызываешь fadeIn когда найдешь  первый попавшийся скрытый див

Comment: Не подскажите, а как написать условие, что бы fadeIn вызывался если все div скрытые?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы проверить, что невидимы все, нужно взять всех, выбрать из них те, который невидимы и сравнить количество.

```
var all = $(".bottom_line_table > div");
var hidden = all.filter(function(){ return ($(this).css("display") == "none"); })

if (all.length == hidden.length){
   // выполняем нужные действия
}
```